# Laravel 5 AWS SDK

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, sdk, composer-php

I am upgrading to L5 this weekend and already have a stopper. I tried both of these in my composer.json file, neither are working upon a composer update.

```
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "1.*"
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel5": "1.*"
```

Error message: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most third-party packages won't be updated for Laravel 5 yet, and this is the case for the AWS SDK. There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/issues/45) for Laravel 5 support you can follow for updates.

If you use a lot of packages, it may be a few months before everything is ported over.